# Spring security access UserDetailsService from deeper layers

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have the following UserDetailsService implementation.
The authentication process is working great so far.
How do I store my "MyUser bean" (**that logged in successfully** ) in the "session" so i can get access to it in other areas in my application

Thanks.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {


    private EmployeesApi employeesApi = new EmployeesApi();

    /**
     * Retrieves a user record containing the user's credentials and access. 
     */
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        // Declare a null Spring User
        UserDetails user = null;

        try {


            MyUser employee = employeesApi.getByUserName(userName);



            user =  new User(
                    employee.getUserName(), 
                    employee.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    true,
                    getAuthorities(1) );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error in retrieving user");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Error in retrieving user");
        }


    }
    ....
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring Security already stores `UserDetails` of authenticated user in session for you.

So, the easiest way to store `MyUser` in session is to implement a custom `UserDetails` that contains a reference to `MyUser`:

```
public class MyUserDetails extends User {
    private MyUser myUser;
    public MyUserDetails(..., MyUser myUser) {
        super(...);
        this.myUser = myUser;
    }
    public MyUser getMyUser() {
        return myUser;
    }
    ...
}
```

And return it from your `UserDetailsService`:

```
MyUser employee = employeesApi.getByUserName(userName);
user =  new MyUserDetails(..., myUser);
```

Then you can easily access `MyUser` via security context:

```
MyUser myUser = ((MyUserDetails) SecurityContextHolder
    .getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getMyUser();
```

In Spring MVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public ModelAndView someController(..., Authentication auth) {
    MyUser myUser = ((MyUserDetails) auth.getPrincipal()).getMyUser();
    ...
}
```

In JSP:

```
<security:authentication var = "myUser" property="principal.myUser" />
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand, can you post simple example? TX!

Comment: And, by the time that i am inside loadUserByUsername, i dont know yet if the login succeeded. so I cant decide if to store it or not. TX!

Comment: @fatnjazzy: You don't need to store it manually. Spring Security will store `UserDetails` automatically after succeessful authentication.

Comment: Thanks, that is working, but i have a question, storing the `MyUser myUser = ((MyUserDetails) auth.getPrincipal()).getMyUser();` in a static method will affect the entire application, what is the best way to allow other layers to have access to it? (I will click on the "V")

Comment: Forget about it, i got it from the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`
Thanks!!!